# Imagick throwing error after PHP 5.6 upgrade

Tags: php, gd, imagick, php-5.6

I just upgraded to PHP 5.6 on my GoDaddy account (PHP 5.6.21), and now I'm encountering an error with Imagick when trying to convert a PDF to images to be rendered on the website.

This is the message I receive:

```
PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-472846ep4mk6vC4cDW%d" "-f/tmp/magick-472846xWEGVMrlFXDu" "-f/tmp/magick-472846grNolFlF8PE2"': -dname= must be followed by a valid token
 @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/263
```

I found this forum thread while on the phone with GoDaddy's support http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26260

and I gathered that the problem only occurs if both GD and Imagick are enabled. Unfortunately I need both - GD won't do what I need, and it turns out MPDF (which I'm using) requires GD to render images.

Has anybody encountered this error before? Is there a way to fix it?

Unfortunately Imagick also can't be updated because GoDaddy is unable to do that for me. #hostingproblems

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update imagick to the next patch.

Shared hosting did not make this possible and eventually we resorting to migrating from our shared hosting plan to a VPS.

If anybody has this problem in the future I strongly suggest moving away from shared hosting. Shared hosting is not suitable for custom code because of problems like this.

If for any reason this is not an option I wish you good luck. Make backups and buy a tub of icecream to ease the impending emotional trauma.